# Enter a value in one cell of a sheet, same value gets log into another sheet and creates a log of values row after row

Tags: microsoft-excel

hope someone can help me out here...

If i have this 4 cells, everytime i enter a value into either one of these cells, it will create a log on another sheet of the same workbook.

For instance, if i have cell B1, C2, B3 and A2 on Sheet 1. If i enter a value into either one of these cells and i press enter, the same value will show up on ...say Cell A2 on Sheet 2. And back onto Sheet 1, after i press enter after a value is entered into one of the 4 cells, the value will disappear and waiting for me to key in the next value to either one of these 4 cells. So the sequence is... enter a value into one of the 4 cells on Sheet 1, it automatically gets logged onto Sheet 2 A2. Next value on Sheet 1 will get log onto Sheet 2 A3 and it goes down the row of Sheet 2... everytime i hit enter (bearing in mind that the value on Sheet 1 of either 1 of the 4 cells needs to disapper after i hit enter).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this, is to put a `Worksheet_Change` function in the worksheet code in `Sheet1` By right-clicking the "Sheet1"-tab and select view code.

**Explanation**

We can use something like this to track the changes in Sheet1:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$1" Or Target.Address = "$C$2" Or Target.Address = "$B$3" Or Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
        MsgBox ("Value changed")
    End If
End Sub
```

This just looks for change in the worksheet, and returns the change as the variable `Target`.
We then check the address of the change with `Target.Address` Which is returned in the `$A$1` form.
A simple `If`statement then checks if the target is any of our specified cells.

Now we need to get the value to the other sheet.
First I want some variables. I call them rSave (the range to save the value) and iRow (Integer that captures the last used row.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim iRow As Integer, rSave As Range
Set rSave = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    If Target.Address = "$B$1" Or Target.Address = "$C$2" Or Target.Address = "$B$3" Or Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
        iRow = rSave(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        rSave.Offset(iRow).Value = Target.Value
        'Target.Value = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

We set the range variable to the cell above where we want to start putting out numbers.
We check for the change and set `iRow`to the last used row of the column in sheet2.
We offset our range with the row from `iRow`and write our target number.

Then we want to set the value in Sheet1 back to nothing. However, this triggers a change in the cells we are tracking and will basically cause an infinite loop.
To get around this we first check if the cell is not empty before trying again.

And we finally end up with this:

**Actual answer**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim iRow As Integer, rSave As Range
Set rSave = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    If Target.Address = "$B$1" Or Target.Address = "$C$2" Or Target.Address = "$B$3" Or Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
        If Target.Value <> "" Then
            iRow = rSave(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            rSave.Offset(iRow).Value = Target.Value
            Target.Value = ""
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Good luck!

*Note that this will save **Anything** entered in the cells of Sheet1. You can limit this by simply adding an `And` at the `If Target.Value <> "" Then` and check for more criteria, like specific numbers or similar.*

Comment: Hello Christofer! Thank you very much for the prompt answer. I shall give it a try later and keep you posted. Just before i try, what about the part of hitting enter or maybe creating a button that when u put a value into either one of those 4 cells and then hit enter or click on a button, the value disappers and then starts the process of logging into Sheet 2 A2 onwards...

Comment: Well, this code monitors changes in the sheet. So when you press enter (or otherwise complete the entry of a value) the code will run. If you want it to run from a button instead, you can do a normal macro. It should be placed in a module, rather than the sheet and start with `sub name()` instead.

Comment: For it to run from a button a bit more change is needed as well, since this still tracks where the change was made. To have it only run when you specifically press enter would be quite advanced.

Comment: Hello Christofer, yes, i do realise that the code will run after i completed an entry or hit enter! Yay! Thanks so much. Now i'm trying to get it to respond to only a certain type of values. Might need some with that soon... :S

Comment: Well currently we check that there is a value with the `If Target.Value <> "" Then`. You could expand on that, and change it to say `If Target.Value <> "" And IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then` To only accept numbers. Editing this if makes it so that if the wrong value is entered (like text), it won't do anything. Not delete it nor copy it. If you still want to delete the wrongly entered value, you should put the if around the row `rSave.Offset(iRow).Value = Target.Value` to just prohibit the copying part.